# Adding time to date query in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-query-builder

I have a query that gets records based on today's date. My problem is that I need it to be todays date and time, not just date. I want to get all records that have a start date and time of today at 9:30am not 12am.

I am using `$today` as the current datetime. Each time a user loads the page, the current datetime is compared to see if it is within the registration period

```
   $today = new DateTime('today');

   $programs = ScheduledProgram::where('registration_start_date', '<=', $today)
                                    ->where('end_date', '>=',  $today)
                                    ->get();
```

My `registration_start_date` field is a `date` type and not `datetime`. But my server is already filled with data.

Is there a way I can add the time to the query to get `registration_start_date + 9:30`?

Or should I run a migration to change the field type of `registration_start_date`? and all the underlying records?

Answer (score 2):

Better you go for Carbon dates. Do the following

```
use Carbon\Carbon
```

In your method add this

```
$today = Carbon::today()->setTime(9,30,0);
```

I tested it. It works. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create variables with a custom date and time range for today, e.g

```
$today_start = date('Y-m-d').' 9:30:00';
$today_end = date('Y-m-d').' 18:30:00';
```

and then use these variables in your query

```
 $programs = ScheduledProgram::where('registration_start_date', '>=', $today_start)
                                ->where('end_date', '<=',  $today_end)
                                ->get();
```

Please note, I change the > and < signs query.

Comment: We are thinking differently about the `$today` variable. I am using `$today` as the current datetime. Each time a user loads the page, the current datetime is compared to see if it is within the registration period.

Comment: sorry I think maybe you are correct...i will try it out and report back.

Comment: We are thinking differently about the start time. It doesn't work the way you described it. I think I need to subtract 9.5 hours from `$today`. The rest of the code can remain the same.